# Error in curl ocurrs when using 'fread' in R

Tags: r, curl, data.table, fread

I was reading a csv file from github using fread of data.table.The code is as follows.

```
input <- if (file.exists("flights14.csv")) {
  "flights14.csv"
} else {
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rdatatable/data.table/master/vignettes/flights14.csv"
}

library(data.table)

flights <- fread(input)
```

An error ocurred:

```
Error in curl::curl_download(input, tmpFile, mode = "wb", quiet = !showProgress) : 
  Could not resolve host: raw.githubusercontent.com
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: using 'read.csv' can get the data,but using 'fread' meets error.

Comment: I run it on my machine and it worked. Does the url works for you if you paste it in browser?

Comment: It works for me as well. The `Could not resolve host` error occurs if you have no internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

You should try opening the link(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rdatatable/data.table/master/vignettes/flights14.csv) in browser when you are connected to Internet. if it works here it should definitely be loaded to your environment when you are passing it to fread function of datatable.

i tried it and it worked out.